# Picasso IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null

Tags: java, android, picasso

Здравствуйте.

Хочу добавить загрузку картинки в `RecyclerView` с URL, но получаю:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
public class IdeaListRecycler extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{



    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    public ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        private PersonAdapter mAdapter;
        //ссылка на вьюшку из представления
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    ImageView imageView2;




    public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String resultJson = "";




            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://malfurion.pythonanywhere.com/rest/get_ideas_list");

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }

                    resultJson = buffer.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return resultJson;
            }




            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
                super.onPostExecute(strJson);
                // выводим целиком полученную json-строку


                JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
                String secondName = "";

                try {
                    dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                    JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                    ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mAdapter = new PersonAdapter(products,IdeaListRecycler.this);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    // 2. перебираем и выводим контакты каждого друга
                    for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);
                        //    JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts");

                        String title = friend.getString("title");
                        String id = friend.getString("id");
                        String sdesc = friend.getString("short_description");
                        String description = friend.getString("description");

                        products.add(new Product(title, sdesc, id, description));

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }



        //ссылка на адаптер, класс который знает всё о модели и дёргает методы холдера

    ParseTask ps;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_idea_list_recycler);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2) ;



            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            //Назначаем вьюхе адаптером наш экземпляр PersonAdapter
            ps = new ParseTask();
            ps.execute();

            //LinearLayoutManager занимается размещением объектов на экране и прокруткой
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


            mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClickListener(this) {
                @Override
                public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(RecyclerView recyclerView, View itemView,
                                        int position) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(IdeaListRecycler.this,IdeaPage.class);
                    Log.d("mesage",products.get(1).title.toString() );

                    intent.putExtra("id",products.get(position).id);
                    intent.putExtra("description",products.get(position).description);
                    intent.putExtra("content",products.get(position).content);
                    intent.putExtra("title",products.get(position).title);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
    }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Нажмите кнопку домой для выхода из приложения",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.idea_list_recycler, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //Кнопка обновить СПИСОК................................................
        if (id == R.id.refreshMenu) {
            try {
                ParseTask nps = new ParseTask();
                nps.execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Intent vovchik = new Intent(this, ShareIdeaActivity.class);
            startActivity(vovchik);

        } else if (id == R.id.media_actions) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }





        private class PersonHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            private TextView mPersonNameTextView;
            private TextView mPersonAdressTextView;
            private TextView mPersonSexTextView;
            private TextView mPersonAgeTextView;
            private Product mPerson;



            public PersonHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mPersonNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                mPersonAdressTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSdesc);

            }
            //Метод, связывающий ранее добытые в конструкторе ссылки с данными модели
            public void bindCrime(Product person) {
                mPerson = person;
                mPersonNameTextView.setText(mPerson.title);
                mPersonAdressTextView.setText(mPerson.content);



            }

        }

        //Наш адаптер, мост между фабрикой клонов и выводом их на экран.
        //Его методы будет дёргать LinearLayoutManager, назныченный вьюшке
        //RecyclerView в методе onCreate нашей активити
        private class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonHolder> {

            private ArrayList<Product> mPersons;
            private Context mContext;
            public PersonAdapter(ArrayList<Product> persons, Context context) {
                mPersons = persons;
                mContext = context;
            }

            //Создаёт пустую вьюшку,оборачивает её в PersonHolder.
            //Дальше забота по наполнению этой вьюшки ложиться именно на объект PersonHolder'а
            @Override
            public PersonHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                View view = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_person, parent, false);
                return new PersonHolder(view);

            }

            //Дёргает метод холдера при выводе нового элемента списка на экран,
            //передавая ему актуальный объект модели для разбора и представления
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(PersonHolder holder, int position) {
                Product person = mPersons.get(position);
                Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
                holder.bindCrime(person);

            }

            //Возвращает размер хранилища моделей
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mPersons.size();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: У вас imageView2 null. И то где вы в него пемещаете картинку-предельно неправильно. Наверное вы хотели в ячейке списка её отобразить.

Comment: Я хочу сделать так что бы загруженная картинка отображалась в каждом пункте списка recyclerview , imageview2 это imageview на макете пункта списка.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `imageView2`, куда Вы хотите загрузить изображение, инициализирован значением `null`.

Инициализировать поле `imageView2` Вы пытаетесь в методе `onCreate(...)` активити:

```
imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2) ;
```

Почему `imageView2` инициализируется значением `null`? – потому что в `R.layout.activity_idea_list_recycler` нет представления с id `imageView2`.

Для того чтобы загрузить изображение в элемент `RecyclerView` Вам необходимо:

1. Добавить Ваш `ImageView` в `R.layout.list_item_person`;
2. В `PersonHolder` объявить поле типа `ImageView`, например `ImageView mImageView`;
3. В конструкторе `PersonHolder()` проинициализировать поле `mImageView`:

   ```
   mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
   ```
4. В методе `onBindBiewHolder(...)` загрузить картинку:

   ```
   Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(holder.mImageView);
   ```

А вообще, правильнее будет загружать изображение в методе `bindCrime(...)` `ViewHolder`'а, коль у Вас он есть.