# Ошибка при загрузке картинки

Tags: listview, picasso

Пытаюсь, загрузить картинку в список ListView, находится в другом layout "list_item.xml" с помощью Picasso

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private String[] imageIdsURL = {};

String res = null;
Context context = this;
private myListAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // ... что-то выполняется

    mAdapter = new myListAdapter(this);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class myListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    myListAdapter(Context context) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nameIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
                .into(image);


        return convertView;
    }

    String getString(int position) {
        return nameIds[position] + " (" + tagsIds[position] + ")";
    }
}
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.part4.loadimgpicasso, PID: 29538
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:
at com.part4.loadimgpicasso.MainActivity$myListAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:118)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2354)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1283)
android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1191)
android.view.View.measure(View.java:18813)
...
```

Очень нужна помощь, что я делаю неверно?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597528/picasso-illegalargumentexception-target-must-not-be-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за внимание, нашел где пропустил оплошность!

```
Context context = this;
```

заменил на

```
Context context;
```

а в остальном, все работало хорошо))